# Cypher - match nodes with similar relations rank result based on number of identical relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, similarity

I have a graph where node/relations look like:

```
(n:Entity)-[r:HasAttribute]->(a:Attribute)
```

All Entity- and Attibute-nodes have a property called id_obj to identify each node
Lets say I have an Entity with id_obj '111' (n:Entity {id_obj:'111'})  and wants to find all other Entity-nodes that has same Attributes as Entity-111 i.e find them having the same Attribute-nodes with same id_obj and rank the result (other Entity nodes) based on the number of same Attribute-nodes.... How do I do that?

I have been looking at: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/alpha/filtered-node-similarity/
but I cant figure out how I can start with one start node (Entity-111) and compare all others. In examples on page it seems like you comparing all nodes and rank them

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the source node(s) by specifying on the **sourceNodeFilter** configuration parameter.  The sourceNodeFilter can be a single node id (or a list of node ids) or single node (or a list of nodes) or a label.

In my example below, I will filter only 'Alice' in line #1 and call it alice.

```
MATCH (alice:Person) where alice.name = 'Alice'
CALL gds.alpha.nodeSimilarity.filtered.stream('myGraph', {sourceNodeFilter: alice, targetNodeFilter:'Singer' } )
YIELD node1, node2, similarity
RETURN gds.util.asNode(node1).name AS Person1, gds.util.asNode(node2).name AS Person2, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESCENDING, Person1, Person2
```

Result:

```
╒═════════╤═════════╤══════════════════╕
│"Person1"│"Person2"│"similarity"      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪══════════════════╡
│"Alice"  │"Bob"    │0.6666666666666666│
├─────────┼─────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Alice"  │"Carol"  │0.3333333333333333│
└─────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Thus, in your example;

```
 MATCH (n:Entity {id_obj:'111'}) 
 CALL gds.alpha.nodeSimilarity.filtered.stream('yourGraph', {sourceNodeFilter: n, targetNodeFilter:'Entity' } )
 and so on...
```

Reference:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/alpha/filtered-node-similarity/#algorithms-filtered-node-similarity-filter-configuration